# Symfony - user gets logged out even on a name change

Tags: php, symfony

I am facing a really weird situation a user with `ROLE_ADMIN` gets logged out as soon as I change the name and even if i dont change anything and press save button it gets logged out. if i change the user's role directly in database to `ROLE_USER` the same code works fine and user is not logged out.

Following is the controller that takes care of the profile update

```
    /**
     * @Route("/profile", name="profile")
     */
    public function profileAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $userInfo = $this->getUser();

        //create the form object
        $profileForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $userInfo);
        $profileForm->handleRequest($request);


        //check data validity
        if($profileForm->isValid()){
            $em->persist($userInfo);
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'success',
                'Your profile information has been updated'
            );

            return $this->render('AppBundle:admin/user:admin-edit.html.twig',array(
                'edit_form' => $profileForm->createView()
            ));
        }


        // render registration form
        return $this->render('AppBundle:admin/user:admin-edit.html.twig',array(
            'edit_form' => $profileForm->createView()
        ));
    }

}
```

This is my `security.yml`

```
security:
    encoders:
        # Our user class and the algorithm we'll use to encode passwords
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    providers:
        # Simple example of loading users via Doctrine
        # To load users from somewhere else: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html
        database_users:
            entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            http_basic: ~
            anonymous: ~
            logout: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.form_login_authenticator
                    - app.facebook_authenticator
                # by default, use the start() function from FormLoginAuthenticator
                entry_point: app.form_login_authenticator
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**UPDATE 1**

This is my `UserType`

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber;
use AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddProfileFieldSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    private $addDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber;
    private $addProfileFieldSubscriver;

    function __construct(AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber $subscriber, AddProfileFieldSubscriber $fields)
    {
        $this->addDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber = $subscriber;
        $this->addProfileFieldSubscriver = $fields;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->addProfileFieldSubscriver);
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->addDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }
}
```

This is my `AddProfileFieldSubscriber`

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\EventListener;


use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;


class AddProfileFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $authorizationChecker;


    function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {


        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();




        if($user){
            $form->add('firstName', TextType::class);
            $form->add('lastName', TextType::class);
            $form->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
                'mapped' => false
            ));
            $form->add('profileImage', FileType::class, array(
                'data_class' => null
            ));
            if (in_array("ROLE_USER", $user->getRoles())) {
                $form->add('contactNumber', TextType::class);

                $form->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Male' => 'm',
                        'Female' => 'f'
                    ),
                    'placeholder' => 'provide_gender'
                ));
                $form->add('college', EntityType::class, array(
                        'placeholder' => 'provide_college',
                        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\College')
                );
                $form->add('interest', EntityType::class, array(
                        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Interest',
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'expanded' => false,
                        'by_reference' => false,
                    )
                );

            }

            if($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')  ) {

                $form->add('isActive', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'account_active' => '1',
                        'account_inactive' => '0'
                    ),
                    'placeholder' => 'provide_status'
                ));
            }

        }
        //if the selected user has role_user only then display the following fields in edit profile view
       else {
            $form->add('username', EmailType::class);
            $form->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
                'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(array(
                        'message' => 'user.password.not_blank'
                    )
                ),),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

This is `AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber`

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\EventListener;


use AppBundle\Entity\Degree;
use AppBundle\Entity\Department;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class AddDepartmentDegreeCourseFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    protected $em;


    function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'onPreSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'onPreSubmit'
        );
    }
    protected function addElements(FormInterface $form, Department $departments = null, Degree $degree = null)
    {

        // Add the department element
        $form->add('department', EntityType::class, array(
                'data' => $departments,
                'placeholder' => 'provide_department',
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Department')
        );
        // Degree are empty, unless we actually supplied a department
        $degree = array();
        if ($departments) {
            // Fetch the courses from specified degree
            $repo = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Degree');
            $degree = $repo->findByDepartment($departments, array('name' => 'asc'));
        }


        // Add the province element
        $form->add('degree', EntityType::class, array(
                'placeholder' => 'provide_degree',
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Degree',
                'choices' => $degree)
        );
        // Cities are empty, unless we actually supplied a province
        $courses = array();
        if ($degree) {
            // Fetch the cities from specified province
            $repo = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Course');
            $courses = $repo->findByDegree($degree, array('name' => 'asc'));
        }
        // Add the Course element
        $form->add('course', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Course',
            'choices' => $courses,
        ));

    }
    function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event) {

        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        if (isset($data['degree'])) {

            // Note that the data is not yet hydrated into the entity.
            $degree = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Degree')->find($data['degree']);
            $department = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Department')->find($data['department']);
            $this->addElements($form, $department, $degree);
        }
    }
    function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        //echo "before submit";die;
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();



        if($user){
            //if the selected user has role_user only then display the following fields in edit profile view
            if (in_array("ROLE_USER", $user->getRoles())) {
                $degree = ( !empty($user) && !empty($user->getCourse())) ? $user->getCourse()->getDegree() : null;
                $departments = ( !empty($user) && !empty($user->getCourse())) ? $user->getCourse()->getDegree()->getDepartment() : null;
                $this->addElements($form, $departments, $degree);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

At this point I am really clueless what could be causing this, I will really appreciate any help here...

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few things wrong in what you've provided.  Elements of which may contribute to the behaviour you're seeing.

**Security rules**

In security.yml, you have this line:

```
- { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Which means that any use without ROLE_ADMIN is going to get shot back to the login screen if they access this pattern.

Meanwhile, in your controller, you're always directing the user back to an Admin based route:

```
/*
 * @Route("admin/profile", name="admin_profile")
 */
```

Which means, no matter what they do, they're always sent to an admin pattern.  This means that if they change their role, they'll be kicked by the firewall.

**Controller**

In your controller you're binding the user entity to a formtype, fine.  But then the way you're coding implies that you don't understand how this works.

When you call `handleRequest`, Symfony pulls the data from the form (if its been submitted), and 'merges' it with the entity that you passed to it.  This means that you don't have to call any setters on the object, as all that's already been done for you.

**User entity**

What you should have on your `User` entity, is a `PlainPassword` field, and a `Password` field.  The form only maps to the `PlainPassword` field.. then, in your controller, take the `PlainPassword` value, encode it, set it to the entity's `Password` field, and make sure you clear the `PlainPassword` value (you dont want to store that). If you've implemented `UserInterface` (which you should have) on your custom user entity, you should have a method called `eraseCredentials`, this is what this is for. [Here is an example](https://github.com/Ampisoft/UserBundle/blob/master/Entity/AbstractUser.php).

The upshot of this is that when you're checking for something, like say, a new password, you only have to do this:

```
if($profileForm->isValid()){
        // $userInfo is populated by handleRequest
        if ($userInfo->getPlainPassword()) {
          // do your encoding/erasing credentials here
        }
        // ...

}
```

What I would also suggest, is that you write a proper `UserManager` class to handle most of those things.  It centralises things and makes it easier to debug.  [Heres an example](https://github.com/Ampisoft/UserBundle/blob/master/Services/AmpUserManager.php)

If you use something such as as I've written in the example, it also means that when you want to update a users info, you only have to call `$userManager->updateUser($user)` and it'll do all the donkey work for you.

Comment: regarding `security.yml` yes its right that in order to access any path that starts with `admin` you need to have `ROLE_ADMIN` so the setup is fine, i get what you are saying about the password and i will get it done that way but what you are suggesting does not solve the problem, suppose if i create a profile route which `ROLE_USER` can access using the same code inside the controller things works fine. its only this `ROLE_ADMIN` that can update it profile perfectly fine but then it get logged out... i am not able to understand why is it getting logged out.

Comment: i updated my question by removing everything inside the controller and keeping it plan and simple, now this code works for `ROLE_USER` but logs `ROLE_ADMIN` out (after saving its data).

Comment: are you sure ROLE_ADMIN is being preserved? can you add the formtype code?

Comment: yes I can confirm that `ROLE_ADMIN` is preserved as I can see it in user table and I have updated my code to show `UserType` and its listeners

Comment: I found the problem, it was `isActive` that was causing the problem, since its only admin that has access to this field so each time i would update my own profile even thought i am changing its value it would sill get updated in database cause me to logout.